# Verb Agreement error?

Tags: verbs, sentence-meaning, subject-verb-agreement

Peter's seemingly effortless flights, achieved through the use of sophisticated technical equipment, continues to delight those who see the play Peter Pan.

In this sentence 'continues' is incorrect, but why?

Comment: Why do you think it's incorrect, more to the point…. or why do you think you think it's incorrect?

Comment: I had a doubt that 'continue' should be used for reasons @ultrasawblade explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Peter's seemingly effortless flights, achieved through the use of sophisticated technical equipment, continues to delight those who see the play Peter Pan.

It's easier to see why if you delete the phrase stuck in the middle between the subject and verb.

> Peter's seemingly effortless flights continues to delight those who see the play Peter Pan.

The subject of *continues* is *flights* - and since *flights* is plural, the verb must be a plural form, so it would be *continue*.